# i want to rename more than 20k files with a script, but it fails: "argument list too long"

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, rename

I create these files by this

```
for((i=0;i<20000;i++)
do
 touch "www.google.com electronic&information this is bash test ${date} .txt"
done
```

Then, I want do replace "www.google.com" to "HNSD" .
in 20k files, all the filenames include the whitespace.

---

My first attempt was the following:

```
rename 's/www.google.com/HNSD/g' *
```

...but this yielded an "argument list too long" error.

---

My second attempt is the following:

```
 #!/bin/bash
function _rename ()
{ 
while read line1; do
#rename 's/www.google.com/HNSD/g' $line1
sed -i "s/www.google.com/HNSD/g" $line1
#echo $line1
done
}

ls -1 | _rename
```

...but this doesn't rename the files given. How should this be done?

Comment: Don't use `ls -1` in scripts. Don't use `read` without `IFS=` preceding it and the `-r` argument after it. Don't use unquoted arguments. And it's not clear how you'd get that error unless you had a longer argument list than will fit on one line passed to a command (such as `sed`) as a *single* line, since the "argument list too long" error is based on each individual external command's argv.

Comment: And `sed -i` doesn't rename files at all; rather, it changes their contents -- so it's not clear how you'd expect this script to accomplish your stated goal.

Comment: Also, don't use the `function` keyword -- it makes your code incompatible with POSIX sh without adding any benefit over the compatible syntax.

Comment: See [ParsingLS](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLS) (on why `ls` should never be used programatically), [BashFAQ #30](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/030) (on renames), and [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) (on correctly using `while read`).

Comment: oh, sorry. I try $rename 's/www.google.com/HNSD/g' * in a directory. It tips argument list too long. Then, i want to create a script and make a circle like which to rename these filenames.

Comment: you could use `printf '%s\0' * | xargs rename 's/www.google.com/HNSD/'`, then.

Comment: BTW, when you talk about an "argument list too long" error, you should really have the code *that produces that exact error* as part of your question itself; as it is, this could be confusing to others since the code you have in the question doesn't match up with the error it reports.

Comment: (Also, consider making a habit of running code through http://shellcheck.net/ -- this will catch bugs like missing quoting; typing `$line1` when it needs to be `"$line1"` can confuse things substantially when `line1` contains spaces).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running a single `mv` command per file won't cause this problem unless the filenames themselves are so long (or your environment is so full, thus crowding out space shared with `argv` use) that you can't fit both source and destination names on the command line at once. The following is thus generally quite safe:

```
for f in *www.google.com*; do
  mv "$f" "${f//www.google.com/HNSD}"
done
```

Here, we're using [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) to perform the rename operation.

---

The original code was problematic because it tried to put *all* filenames on the command line at once. If you use `xargs` or `find -exec {} +` to split your operation into multiple invocations, you won't have that problem. If you have `rename`, and want to call it as few times as possible to process all directory entries for the current location, that would look like the following:

```
printf '%s\0' * | xargs -0 rename 's/www.google.com/HNSD/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

---

Use `find`, and rename using `rename` (or similar) within the `-exec` action:

```
find . -type f -name '*www.google.com*' -exec rename 's/www.google.com/HNSD/g' {} +
```

---

Leverage a `for` loop to iterate over the files:

```
for f in *www.google.com*; do rename 's/www.google.com/HNSD/g' "$f"; done
```